# How to pass a metadata to a Stripe Webhook, using javascript in Stripe Elements

Tags: javascript, html, angular, stripe-payments

I am following the instructions in this stripe [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js). The backend expects me to pass metadata among the Stripe object I am going to send. The metadata is expected to connect with a webhook.

The problem I am having is in the Stripe documentation, there's no sample I have seen where this is done in the frontend.

I am trying to do this using Angular and here is my code snippet:

**app.component.ts**

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
   if(this.stripe) {
    const element = this.stripe.elements()
    this.card = element.create('card', {style: this.style});
    
    // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
    this.card.on('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});
}
}


onSubmit(){
setTimeout(() => {
this.card.mount('#card-element');
// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
this.card.on('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});
}, 3000);
```

and **app.component.html**

```
<form #form id="payment-form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="card-element">
        Credit or debit card
      </label>
      <div id="card-element">
        <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
      </div>
  
      <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    </div>
    <button>Submit Payment</button>
  
    <!-- <div id="payment-request-button"> -->
      <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    <!-- </div> -->
    </form>
```

So, where can I pass a metadata in the object above?

Comment: Webhook event notifications will be sent directly to your server as the result of API actions. Nothing in the code above is actually making an API request. Can you share a bit more code that shows the server calls you're making?

Comment: Here in lies the issue. The backend developer says I don't need to make an API call. All I need to do is to send a meta data. So do you think that is achievable?

Comment: You must at some point make an API call. Also, webhooks are entirely backend and dont interact at all with the client.